# How to handle a selection screen with zen page, using selenium python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[This image shows where I open the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkYym.png)

[This is the window I would like to scroll on and get the lowest option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNGTg.png)

The html to it is as follows:

```html
<td style="white-space: nowrap">

<input class="comboboxInput" type="text" readonly="" id="input_52" size="3" value="10" onkeydown="zenPage.getComponent(52).inputKeyHandler(event);" onblur="zenPage.getComponent(52).inputBlurHandler(event);" onchange="zenPage.getComponent(52).inputChangeHandler();">

<img src="images/combobox.png" id="btn_52" onmousedown="zenPage.getComponent(52).comboboxButtonDown(event);" onmouseup="zenPage.getComponent(52).comboboxButtonUp();" onmouseover="zenPage.getComponent(52).comboboxMouseOver();" onmouseout="zenPage.getComponent(52).comboboxMouseOut();" class="comboboxImgButton" onclick="zenPage.getComponent(52).showDropdown();">

</td>
```

I've tried to use the following code to bypass it, got an error in return

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='input_52']").value = 2000  #2000 being the highest value on the list
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  What error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JavaScript to change value:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('input_52').setAttribute('value', '2000');")
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you try clicking on the element first and then capture the values?

Comment: I've tried to get the path to the values, but when i try inspecting them i get the path to whats behind

Comment: What is the error ? You can use explicit wait for the values to appear.